# How to sort dice and create new arrays with equal dice in each array, Yahtzee, C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I'm making an Yahtzee game in C++, my goal is to make an intelligent play field there the game will give examples to the user where he or she can put the result. In order to do that I have to sort the dices from low to high and then make new arrays, one array for those dices equal each other and the size of each array has to be as big as the number of dices in it.

This is my base-class:

The funktion that throws each dice.

```
void InGame::setDice(int dice){
    if (this->diceCapacity <= this->nrOfDices){
        this->expandDice();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nrOfDices; i++){
        die[i]->roll(6);
    }
}
```

setDice works fine. After this I'm sorting all 5 dices in a sub-class called scoreCalculator.

The sorting funktion:

```
void ScoreCalculator::sortDie(int arr[], int nrOfDieces){
    int temp = -1;
    int minIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nrOfDieces - 1; i++){
        minIndex = i;
        for (int k = (i + 1); k < nrOfDieces; k++){
            if (arr[k] < arr[minIndex]){
                minIndex = k;
            }
        }
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[minIndex];
        arr[minIndex] = temp;
    }
}
```

And now I'm going to fill each equal die into different arrays that just holds those dices that are equal to each other.

This is what I have done so far

```
void ScoreCalculator::equalDie(int dice[]){
    dice[5];
    this->sortDie(dice, 5);
    int count = 0;
    int equal[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for (int x = 1; x < 6; x++){
            if (dice[i] == dice[x]){
                for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++){
                    equal[y] = dice[i];
                    equal[y + 1] = dice[x];
                    y++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This last funktion is not working at all

Comment: Regarding the sorting, can't you just use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Comment: I don't understand. Is that a way of sorting integers?
Im have "using namespace std" in every file, Maybe I should have mentioned that

Comment: Pedantic: It is one 'die', multiple 'dice'. 'dices' would be correct in 'He dices the potatoe into small cubes', but is never correct when talking of small cubes [or other shapes] with dots on each side.

Comment: thanks @MatsPetersson I will remember that

Comment: `std::sort` can sort any range of values which have a valid `<` operator defined, and if there isn't you can provide your own comparison function. In your case try e.g. `std::sort(arr, arr + nrOfDieces);`

Comment: Off Topic:  You don't need to use `this->` syntax when accessing class members; access them correctly.  It saves you typing time.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::vector` instead of an array.  Arrays lose attributes, such as size and capacity, when passed to a function, so you will have to pass more parameters when using an array.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate that things are easier without c style array I've created a class `Roll` that contains the results of a roll of die. That class could use a `vector` to store the values of the die. Then `std::sort` can be used to sort the die and `vector::operator==` can be used to compare rolls for equality. A method `counts` could return the roll in a format where index `i` is the number of die with value `i+1`. Roll might look like this:

```
class Roll
{
public:

    Roll()
        : die_( 6 )
    {
        roll();
    }

    void roll()
    {
        std::generate_n( die_.begin(), 6, [&] { return dist_( rng_ ); } );

        std::sort( die_.begin(), die_.end() );
    }

    friend bool operator==( Roll const& lhs, Roll const& rhs )
    {
        return lhs.die_ == rhs.die_;
    }

    friend bool operator!=( Roll const& lhs, Roll const& rhs )
    {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }

    std::vector<int> counts() const
    {
        std::vector<int> counts(6, 0);

        for( char dice : die_ )
            counts[dice-1]++;

        return counts;
    }

private:

    static std::mt19937 rng_;
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist_;

    std::vector<char> die_;
};
```

A simple roll of two dice, checking for equality and outputting the number of dies for each of the six possible values would look like this:

```
Roll r1;
Roll r2;
bool equal = r1 == r2;

std::cout << equal << std::endl;

auto c1 = r1.counts();
auto c2 = r2.counts();

for( int i = 0; i < 6; ++i  )
{
    std::cout << i + 1 << " : " << c1[i] << " " << c2[i] << std::endl;
}
```

**<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7ba6069156b2f06)</kbd>**